# What dot means in JTDX FT8 received messages?

Tags: software, ft8

What dot near country means in JTDX? Maybe LOTW?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it means lotw. I'm looking for some documentation about it so I can write a proper answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found on the [JTDX groups.io](https://jtdx.groups.io/g/main/message/6797?p=,,,20,0,0,0::relevance,,new+symbols,20,2,0,28993897) (link won't work without login, unfortunately):

> sybmol • - this operator loaded his log into LoTW
>   symbol ° - this operator loaded his log into LoTW and this is Hint decode (FT8 AP or matched filter based decoder in JT65 JT9 T10 modes)
>   symbol * - Hint decode (FT8 AP or matched filter based decoder in JT65 JT9 T10 modes)

So the solid dot and the open dot both mean LoTW user. Star doesn't (it means the same thing that it does in wsjt-x).